# I tried to make a game but this happened

Tags: python, ursina

```
from ursina import *
from ursina.prefabs.first_person_controller import FirstPersonController

class Box(Button):
    def __init__(block='grass.obj',texture='grasstex.png',pose:tuple=(0,0,0)):
        super().__init__(model=block,texture=texture, collider='mesh',position=pose)

app=Ursina()
tp=50
for x in range(tp):
    for z in range(tp):
        Box(pose=(x,0,z))

player=FirstPersonController()
player.z=player.x=0
Sky()
app.run()
```

It gave me this error:

**Assertion failed: reparented at line 407 of panda/src/pgraph/nodePath.cxx
Assertion failed: Detected attempt to create a cycle in the scene graph: ui_render/ui_camera/ui/box : PandaNode box at line 2637 of c:\buildslave\sdk-windows-amd64\build\panda\src\pgraph\pandaNode.cxx**

What should I do?

Comment: StackOverflow is not meant to be a place to copy-paste your code and errors, you need to also precise what you want to do and what you have already tried. At least put a title which indicates what exactly you're talking about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot the `self` parameter in your `Block` constructor:

```py
class Box(Button):
    def __init__(self, block='grass.obj', texture='grass', pose:tuple=(0,0,0)):
        super().__init__(
            parent=scene,
            model=block,
            texture=texture, 
            collider='mesh',
            position=pose)
```

Every method in a Python object will receive its instance as the first parameter. I also had to explicitly assign `parent=scene` or else the boxes would get attached to the camera UI, even though the documentation says otherwise.